# Python script not working but does not give me errors (Pandas, NLTK)

Tags: python, pandas, nltk

I'm trying to remove all stop words from my keyword list so I can get better results from a topic modeling script I've been using. Not sure what I am doing wrong here, I'm rather new to using python. I would simply like to take keywords from the column "keyword" and remove the stop keywords and insert the output into a new column "clean_keyword". It is important that I keep the original keywords.

Here is my script:

```
import pandas as pd

import nltk.corpus
nltk.download('stopwords')
from nltk.corpus import stopwords

df = pd.read_csv('keywords_to_cluster.csv')

stop_words = stopwords.words('english')
df['clean_keyword'] = df['keyword'].apply(lambda x: ' '.join([word for word in x.split() if word not in (stop_words)]))
```

The script runs without errors when I execute from my venv with the command,

```
python cleanup_keywords.py
```

Although there is no output in my CSV file.

I have simply been following [this guide](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-clean-text-data-639375414a2f) so please forgive me if I have missed something simple, but I am at a loss here.

Comment: Since it is not shown in your code - did you actually save the CSV again? What do you mean by there is no output in your CSV file.

Comment: i see.. gotcha. I knew I had to be missing something extremely simple... yes adding this code worked:

df.to_csv('keywords_to_cluster.csv')

Thank you so much, I do apologize for my ignorance.
